# apply function pandas dataframe

Tags: python, function, pandas, apply

I'm trying to apply a simple function to a pandas dataframe. I want to achieve a variable called "target", from the formula defined in "my_res", and add it to the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','2','3'], 'v1': [0,2,3], 'v2':[1,4,5], 'v3':[11,43,52]})
print df


def my_res (x,y,z):
    target=(x*z)/y
    return target


df['target'] = df.apply(my_res('v1','v2','v3'),axis=1)
print df
```

and what if I had a formula like this:

```
def my_res (x,y,z):
    target=(x*z)/y
    check=target-z
    return target

#in this case I want to create 2 variable in the df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` with column names:

```
df['target'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_res(x.v1,x.v2,x.v3),axis=1) 
print (df)
  ID  v1  v2  v3  target
0  1   0   1  11     0.0
1  2   2   4  43    21.5
2  3   3   5  52    31.2
```

But better and faster is use vectorized solutions with [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html), [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) and [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df['target'] = df.v1 * df.v3 /df.v2
print (df)
  ID  v1  v2  v3  target
0  1   0   1  11     0.0
1  2   2   4  43    21.5
2  3   3   5  52    31.2
```

---

```
df['target'] = df.v1.mul(df.v3).div(df.v2)
print (df)
  ID  v1  v2  v3  target
0  1   0   1  11     0.0
1  2   2   4  43    21.5
2  3   3   5  52    31.2
```

**Timings**:

```
def my_res (x,y,z): 
    target=(x*z)/y 
    return target

#[30000 rows x 4 columns]    
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df['target'] = df.v1.mul(df.v3).div(df.v2)
df['target1'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_res(x.v1,x.v2,x.v3),axis=1) 
print (df)

In [290]: %timeit df.v1.mul(df.v3).div(df.v2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 305 µs per loop

In [291]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: my_res(x.v1,x.v2,x.v3),axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.66 s per loop

In [292]: %timeit df.v1 * df.v3 / df.v2
1000 loops, best of 3: 562 µs per loop
```

Comment: thanks, I added a generalization detail to my question

Comment: Sure, you can use `df['target'] = df.v1.mul(df.v3).div(df.v2).sub(df.v3)`
`df['target'] = df.v1 * df.v3 /df.v2 - df.v3`. `apply` solution are used if vectorized approach is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use apply here. A simple vectorized operation will work.

```
df.v1 * df.v3 / df.v2
```